# AutoMapper NamingConvention - why doesn't this work?

Tags: c#, automapper

New to Automapper - Confused why this doesn't work...Thanks!!!!

```
public class Dog
{
    public string Bark { get; set; }
}

public class Pig
{
    public string bark { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
            cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
        });
        var map = Mapper.Map<Pig, Dog>(new Pig());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific what doesn't work?

Comment: {"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nPig -> Dog\r\nConsoleApplication1.Pig -> ConsoleApplication1.Dog\r\n\r\nDestination path:\r\nDog\r\n\r\nSource value:\r\nConsoleApplication1.Pig"}

Answer (score 3):

You should use DynamicMap:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    #region

    using AutoMapper;

    #endregion

    internal class Program
    {
        #region Methods

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(
                cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
                    cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
                });
            var dog = Mapper.DynamicMap<Pig, Dog>(
                new Pig
                {
                    bark = "Bark!"
                });
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class Dog
    {
        #region Public Properties

        public string Bark { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }

    public class Pig
    {
        #region Public Properties

        public string bark { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Or configure AutoMapper first:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Pig, Dog>();

        var dog = Mapper.Map<Dog>(
            new Pig
            {
                bark = "Bark!"
            });
```

That's all.